# Python string splitting

Tags: python, string, split

If I have a string `'x=10'`, how can I extract the 10 as an integer using one line of code?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: split, int, len, assert

Comment: "One line" isn't important, but I understand you to mean simple, clear code.

Comment: No not homework, just trying to learn python

Comment: Four different solutions, each upvoted, meaning they provide some value to visitors and thus the question also provides value, yet the question is downvoted. That's not the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> s = "x=10"
>>> int(s.split('=')[-1])
10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
s = 'x=10' 
i = int(s[2:])
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
a = "x=10"
b = int(a.split('=')[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
result = int(my_string.rpartition("=")[-1])
```

Note, however, that if there is anything else after the `=` sign the function will break.

So `x=10`, `x=560`, and `x=1010001003010` will all work.  However, `y=1,341` will break with a  ValueError.

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,341'`

**Edit:**
Actually, pitrou's use of `split` is even better, since you probably are not guaranteed that there will be only one `=` sign either.

And also fixed the `partition` vs. `rpartition` problem.

Comment: To account for the possibility of something like `x=y=500`, I would use `rpartition` instead of `partition`.

Comment: **OP doesn't have such problem**. With you attitude we'll get to parsing random binary blobs because these *numbers* are not guaranteed to be at end of string, not guaranteed to be digits, not guaranteed to be ascii strings.

Comment: @SilentGhost -- absolutely true.  I wasn't trying to suggest that his code **should** be robust enough to handle `1,341`, only pointing out that it wouldn't.  A note of caution, rather than a suggestion that a more "robust" solution was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
answer = int("x=10".partition("=")[2])
```